# WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration throws Failed to map the path '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using:

```
Configuration objConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

but unfortunately it throws **Failed to map the path '/' error**.
I am also tried to provide physical application path, but still its not working....

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem with the line you have here. You could try to do it this way as well:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration objConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

If that fails try to "Enable Parent Paths" from your IIS by following the following steps:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. On the Connections pane, expand the server node and select your site from underneath "Sites."
3. On the Features view, double-click "ASP."
4. Change "Enable Parent Paths" to "True."
5. Under the Actions page, click "Apply."
6. Restart IIS and see if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by running Visual Studio as administrator. I saw this error on a Windows 7 system, when on one system the same code worked perfectly well, but not on the other and running VS as admin solved the issue for us.

Here's a [reference](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2007/12/01/WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration-throws-Failed-to-map-the-path-_27002F0027002E00_.aspx) on the same issue and same solution for Vista.